# Detect browser keyboard IME feature

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, chromium

The problem: I'm working hard to implement a responsive UI in my app. But the keyboard IME on Android squishes my entire page layout into a frame that's about 96 pixels high when in landscape orientation. Typically this means that the input control being edited is not visible in the space above the IME. And one cannot edit a value that's not visible in Chromium. I'm assuming iOS has the same problem.

Setting a minimum height for the page helps. But the Chromium scroll-into-view implementation is not robust enough to keep up with some of the more complex page rewrites that are triggered by a change in window size in my app.

Ideally, I'd like to run the keyboard IME in "extract" mode, where the page is entirely hidden, and only the value being edited is displayed in the space above the IME. But as far as I can tell, there's no way to do that, even in Android native apps. Chromium never runs the keyboard IME in "extract" mode, even in landscape orientation.

The solution I'm current implementing: simulate "extract" IME mode by perform editing of values in a full-screen dialog that contains nothing but a single dedicated `<input>`.

The question is: how should I detect when to use this solution. it's easy enough to check the browser's `navigator.userAgent`. The Mozilla foundation recommends checking for `/Mobi|Android/` (although I've seen solutions that have 40 or 50 patterns).  But I'm wondering whether there's a feature-driven way to check for this instead -- something more along the lines of `if ("geolocation" in navigator) ...`.

But as far as I can tell, there are no features related to whether and how a keyboard IME will change the layout of a page. If there are, I'd like to know.  The "feature" I'm looking for is something along the lines of "Will this browser lay out my entire page in a frame that's 96 pixels high (in landscape) whenever an input control gets focus". But "does this browser uses a keyboard IME" would be satisfactory.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Different use-case, but same problem. There doesn't seem to be any way to detect the difference between IME/non-IME.